# viewing custom listview items in android

Tags: android, listview

when I add the first item it works correctly but when I add the 2nd one it shows listView items' layout but there isn't any data in text box like these pics:
[ScreenShot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2D4P0.png),
[ScreenShot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TUvL.png)

My Adapter Code:

```
public class Myadp extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private String[] data;
Context context;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
public Myadp(Context context, int resource, int textViewItem, String[] strings) {
    super(context, resource, textViewItem, strings);
    this.data = strings;
    this.context = context;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listtemp, null, true);
    TextView textView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView.setText(this.data[position]);
    return row;
}}
```

**I made an app few months ago in android studio and I use `inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);` instead of `inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);` but now android studio doesn't recognize it**

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_item_venue, parent, false);

    // findViewByIds...

    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

//set your data to TextView or what you have to do;

    return convertView;
}
```

This way list will reuse created rows and if they don't exist already, it will create them.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View row = convertView;
if(row == null){
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listtemp, null, true);
}
    TextView textView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView.setText(this.data[position]);
    return row;
}
```

}

Comment: Because it is not using inflated row again , he is creating each row again and again.

Comment: I used to use inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); but now Android studio doesn't recognize it

Comment: Don't make inflater static